# Terminal on Mac won't launch a shell - stuck on login: incorrect

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, bash, login

I've been having this issue for a while where I come to open the Terminal and I'm met with this:

```
Login incorrect
login: _
```

I've already deleted the com.apple.terminal.plist to no avail. The really interesting thing is that *sometimes* it works, maybe 1 in 50 times. I literally have no idea what might be causing it and after searching the web for the better part of half a day it seems everyone else's issues are fixed when they delete the plist file.

How do I sort this out? I've tried running different shells (bash and zsh), but I still get this log in screen.

Also when I use Activity Monitor, I can see there is no shell running just the login.

[image: Terminal Error]

Comment: Have you tried clicking Default login shell - when terminal start no login sheall has run yet - OSX is nt the same as many other Unices here

Comment: Another thing to try is invoking that shell manually to see if it reveals any clues:
1. Choose **Shell > New Command…**.
2. Enter `/bin/bash`.
3. Click **Run**.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was:

1. Completely close all terminal windows.
2. Open Finder from the Dock.
3. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and type in `~/Library/Preferences/`, then press enter.
4. Locate the file called `com.apple.Terminal.plist` and rename it (using highlight and then single click) to `com.apple.Terminal.OLD.plist`.
5. Re-open the terminal app.

Note that the file might also show up in Finder as `com.apple.Terminal` if you do not show extensions by default.

Comment: Manipulating Preference files directly is not recommended and will not always work, because it is managed by a process that caches the contents. To reset Preferences, run `defaults delete com.apple.Terminal`.

Comment: The only preference that is likely to affect this is the “**Shells open with**” preference mentioned in the question. Resetting all preferences should be used only as a last resort if changing specific preferences doesn't help.